# Is there any way I can call my shell script in Java and set values to the shell script variables via Java class

Tags: java, shell, sh

I have a shell script file which has three variables defined in it. I need to set values for those variable in java class, which means, I need to get access of the shell script file in my Java class, then I need to get access of those three variables, and then I need to set values of those three variables from Java. I am not sure how to achieve this requirement. My shell script file is located in windows D:/.
Here is my shell script code:

```
path=`xxx`
echo "$path"

Src
Dest
Env
```

I need to set the value of `Src`, `Dest` and `Env`

Comment: Generally we start Java application using script and pass necessary argument.  do the same pass those defined values Java main file.  java -jar Main.java argument1 argument 2

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Since I am very new to shell script, could you kindly suggest the above solution codewise. Thanks in advance

Comment: What's your environment(s?) like? Are you able to execute that bash script on your windows platform (e.g. using git bash, cygwin or the likes)?

Comment: Yes, I am able to execute the bash script in my windows platform using git bash.

Comment: You can find many online

Comment: https://github.com/san4net/cp/tree/master/src/main/resources/script

Comment: The above link has java codes written in shell script file i guess. My requirement is to access those variables in my Java code. So lets assume that if I run the Java file with main method, I get to see those variable in console, or I could be able to set those variables with any hard coded strings.

Answer (score 0):

A process inherits a copy of all environment variables from its parent process, which is the process that runs it.

So if you want to set environment variables in a Java program and use them in a shell script, you need the Java program to run the shell script.

That is possible using the java.lang.ProcessBuilder class, but quite unusual. Are you sure it's what you want?

If you need the java program to get the values of the variables, and then use them in the shell script, you could have the java program write the values to a file and then read them from the file in your script, which is likely to be simpler, easier and more portable.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. If we use ProcessBuilder, I want to know how can we achieve the above ? What are the limitations if I use ProcessBuilder ?

Comment: Using ProcessBuilder you will want to call the git bash command (or any other bash interpreter you'd have available on your platform) with the path to your script as an argument and either rely on environment variables previously set using System.setEnv or specify the environment variables through processBuilder.environment(). Check [the ProcessBuilder javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html), it should tell you all you need to know